# Tableau creating a calculated percentage (non-aggregate) based on an aggregated total

Tags: tableau-api

Either I am the first person to ever need to display percentages in Tableau or I do not know what to search for! I highly suspect it is the latter...

I believe what I am attempting to ask is how to make a calculated non-aggregated field by dividing by an aggregated number. Although I would prefer just to be able to display the percentages instead of a whole number.

This is how I would do it in Excel:

[image]

The data that already exists is Column A and B. In Tableau these would be non-aggregated. What I need to do in Tableau is to generate what is column C (also non-aggregated) because it does not exist in my data. In excel, all I did to get the aggregate number (total) of column B was:

`sum(B1:B4)`

And for the column C:

`=B1/$B$5`

But I can't seem to do this at all in Tableau. When I try to use the same syntax, I get an error message: "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of having a calculated field, you can use a Quick Table Calculation on the column.

Right-click the pill of your data > Quick Table Calculation > Percent of Total. This will show the percentages instead. If you want to keep both, just duplicate column b first and then add the table calculation to the new column.

Comment: then playing with the compute using setting (or the table calc editor) can adjust the scope of your percentage calculations as desired

Comment: Why take such a simple calculation and make it so difficult and unintuitive?!?!